# Previous file as first entry on quickopen

Tags: intellij-idea, visual-studio-code

When you use quickopen, it will show you the file you are currently editing as the first entry. In for example IntelliJ it will show you the file you previously opened, which makes it possible to quickly swap between 2 files using quickopen + enter.

Is there any option to have this in vsc either? I dont really get, why you would have the current file as the first entry, its rather unlikely you are going to open the same file again or am I missing a reason for it?

Comment: **Ctrl** + **Tab**?

Comment: I changed that binding, do you know which standard binding is on ctrl-tab?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

Mac: hold down `⌘` and press `P` twice.

Windows: hold down `CTRL` and press `P` twice.

### Option 2

Hold down `CTRL` and press `Tab`.

### Option 3

1. Go to `Code > Preference > Keyboard Shortcuts`
2. Type `Open Next Recently Used Editor in Group` into the search bar.
3. When that command shows up, click the edit icon and add your own custom shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Now see [VS Code: How to configure Go to File command to auto-select the previous file (like Sublime)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59165299/vs-code-how-to-configure-go-to-file-command-to-auto-select-the-previous-file-l/59166104#59166104)

A command was added to vscode: `workbench.action.quickOpenPreviousEditor` in October 2017 which can be used in a keybinding like so:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+p",
  "command": "-workbench.action.quickOpen"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+p",  // or cmd
  "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenPreviousEditor"
}
```