# VS Code: How to configure Go to File command to auto-select the previous file (like Sublime)

Tags: sublimetext3, visual-studio-code

If I trigger the *Go to File* command in Sublime, don't type anything, and hit enter it auto-selects the previously viewed file:

[image]

In VS Code, the *Go to File* command auto-selects the current file, which means I have to type the file name or hit the down arrows.

[image]

**What setting do I need to change so that the previously viewed file is auto selected if I trigger the *Go to File* command?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such setting, but see the same issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26977 (Select previous file by default when using Ctrl-P).  The solution is to add this to your keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+p",  // or cmd
  "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenPreviousEditor"
}
```

Now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> will open the file quickopen panel with the previous file selected.

If you prefer the "Go to File..." keybinding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> then you should use that in the above new keybinding instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you @Mark