# How can I have first suggestion as the last document in Visual Studio's Command Palette?

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code

I just switched from Sublime. In sublime, when you use `Command+P` the recent files show up, just like in vscode.

However, there's a key difference in sublime vs vscode. In Sublime, the first result will be the LAST opened file. In vscode it's the current file, which is, rather illogical to be honest.

How can I have the first result to be the last file, and not the current file? This will allow for way faster switching between two documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Previous file as first entry on quickopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47943465/previous-file-as-first-entry-on-quickopen)

These keybindings will not move the previous file to the top entry but it will select the previously opened file instead of the top current file.

```
 {
    "key": "ctrl+p",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenPreviousEditor"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+p",
    "command": "-workbench.action.quickOpen"
  },
```

Also see [How can I go back to previous tab opened in VScode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56077745/how-can-i-go-back-to-previous-tab-opened-in-vscode/59941711#59941711)

v1.42 added some new functionality to open the previous recently used files.